# Extending ArcGIS Metadata Style?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcobjects, arcgis-online, metadata

I want to extend metadata style. I want to add three new fields in metadata of feature class.

I know there are different standards of metadata which ArcGIS Supports.

Is there any way or possibility to have my own standard or customize some existing and made it available in ArcGIS in my organization?

I know that there is a way to create an xml file in catalog and view it as meta data and do the changes and use it as template, but can i add new fields even to this template?

If yes, Can i use that in ArcGIS Portal too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One Approach is to use ArcGIS Metadata toolkit.

https://support.esri.com/en/download/7511

To do this You can

- Document the XML format in which an item’s metadata is made available to the metadata editor.
- Change the manner in which metadata is displayed.
- Change the settings used to populate the metadata geoprocessing tools when buttons are clicked in the Description tab.
- Specify the Translator used to export metadata to a standard XML format.
- Specify if and how the metadata may be validated using an XML Schema or XML DTD.
- Change the pages included in the metadata editor, except for the Item Description page, which must be included.
- Change the values provided in drop-down lists in the metadata editor.
- Change the validation rules associated with the content that can be provided in the metadata editor.
- Change the elements included in an existing metadata page, except for metadata elements that are required by ArcGIS software.
- Add a custom metadata element to a page and to the ArcGIS metadata format.
- Add a custom page to the metadata editor.

Second approach is to use Geoportal Server.
It is an open source product which allows meta data customization and has integration options available with Esri ArcMap and Server and Portal. 
It allows you to create your own standard. There is option to re-use and extend existing standards.

Required steps as describe on their github

https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Add-a-Custom-Profile#profile-customization-process-step-by-step

- Develop a plan for your profile
- Copy the required files
- Update your template.xml file
- Update your definition.xml file
- Update gpt.properties
- Define how elements are indexed for search
- Update schemas.xml
- Finishing your profile

For this product details refer to their Github Page

https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server

Esri page for this product

https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/geoportal-server/overview

Answer (score 1):

The best approach and guidance I know of is [Creating a metadata template](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/metadata/creating-a-metadata-template.htm):

> When you need to create metadata for many ArcGIS items, it helps to streamline the task by creating a metadata template. Like a map document template or Word document template, a metadata template contains information that will be used again and again. With ArcGIS automatically updating properties of an item and metadata templates in place, it takes much less effort to complete an item's metadata. You can focus on documenting important information like the sources and quality of your data.

> In the Catalog window, right-click the folder where you want to store the metadata template.
>   Click New > XML Document.
>   A new XML file Stand-alone Metadata XML File with the default name New_XML_Document.xml is created in the folder. The item's name can instantly be modified to something more appropriate.
>
> Type an appropriate name for the metadata template.
>   Press ENTER.
>   View the XML file as metadata.
>   The file doesn't contain any information to display in the Description tab.
>
> Click the Edit button Edit Metadata in the Description tab.
>   Type in appropriate content for this metadata template.
>   Click the Save button Save Metadata Edits in the Description tab.
>   The contents of the metadata template will be displayed.

Comment: Yes i know this one, what i want is to have three new fields (which are not present once i view metadata) When i said i want to have my own standard or customize some existing i meant to extend some existing standard) e.g. There is summary field, description field similarly i want to add three more fields.
I have updated the question